# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException why?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I would like to make a tic tac toe console game for my university. This is the code below

the main program:

```
import acm.program.*;
public class askisi1d extends Program {
    public void run(){
        tictac player[];
        player=new tictac[2];
        player[0]=new tictac("baggelis");
        player[1]=new tictac("Giorgaras");
        player[0].setMove("1 2");
        println(tictac.drawTable());

    }

}
```

This is the class code:

```
import java.util.*;
import acm.program.*;
public class tictac{
    private String name;
    int [][]table=new int [][]{
    {8,1,6},
    {3,5,7},
    {4,9,2}
    };
    int activePlayer;
    boolean [][]takenSquare= new boolean [2][2];
    int [][]playerTable; //gia tin niki
    static tictac[] player;
    private int row;  //<---
    private  int col;  //""
    public tictac(String name){
        this.name=name;
        playerTable=new int[2][2];
        activePlayer=0;
    }
    public boolean isValidMove(int row,int col){
        return (row>0&&row<4&&col>0&&col<4&&takenSquare[row-1][col-1]==false);
    }//isValidmove
    public void setMove (String move){
        StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(move);
        this.row= Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        this.col= Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        if (isValidMove(row-1,col-1)){
            player[activePlayer].takenSquare[row-1][col-1]=true;
            player[activePlayer].playerTable[row-1][col-1]=table[row-1][col-1];
        }
        activePlayer=1-activePlayer;
    }
    public static String drawTable(){

        String a="";
        a+=(drawSquare(0,0)+"|");
        a+=(drawSquare(0,1)+"|");
        a+=(drawSquare(0,2)+'\n');
        a+=("-----------")+'\n';
        a+=drawSquare(1,0)+"|";
        a+=drawSquare(1,1)+"|";
        a+=(drawSquare(1,2)+'\n');
        a+=("-----------")+'\n';
        a+=drawSquare(2,0)+"|";
        a+=drawSquare(2,1)+"|";
        a+=(drawSquare(2,2));
        return"a";
    }

    public static String drawSquare(int x,int y){
        if (player[0].isTaken(x,y)) {
            return "O";
        }   else if (player[1].isTaken(x,y)) return "X";
        else return "   ";  

    }
    public boolean isTaken(int x,int y) {
        return takenSquare[x][y];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error in?

Comment: `takenSquare` elements seem to be `null`. Make sure you initialize them.

Comment: in line if (player[0].isTaken(x,y)) { in the class file 

an in the line a+=(drawSquare(0,0)+"|"); 

and in the main program  println(tictac.drawTable()); there. 

how can i initialaze them ?? :/ im a begginer.. by the way are u from greece ?

Comment: You're allocating `takenSquare` as a 2-by-2 array but you're indexing into it with indexes 0, 1, and 2, so `takenSquare` should be allocated as 3-by-3. However, that should cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @shoover i just compiled. this didnt solve the problem..

Comment: Yeah, it was just another problem that you were going to run into if you solved your NPE.

Comment: How about the full stacktrace?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2i6xmz the full stacktrace

Comment: `static tictac[] player` is not initialized, right?

Comment: @user270349 i guess..

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems:

You already have static play array defined within your `tictac` class. `run()` defines a local copy of it and as soon as you invoke `drawTable()`, it takes the uninitialized static array ignoring what you have in `run()`.

You can either make a proper use of static variables by initializing them.
Quick and dirty check is to write the main method within your tictac class and comment out the local version of the array.

Something like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

                    //TicTac player[];
                    player=new TicTac[2];
                    player[0]=new TicTac("baggelis");
                    player[1]=new TicTac("Giorgaras");
                    player[0].setMove("1 2");
                    System.out.println(TicTac.drawTable());


        }
```

As pointed out in the comments, now you would run into `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception hence make those changes, modified code below:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TicTac{
    private String name;
    int [][]table=new int [][]{
    {8,1,6},
    {3,5,7},
    {4,9,2}
    };
    int activePlayer;
    boolean [][]takenSquare= new boolean [3][3];
    int [][]playerTable; //gia tin niki
    static TicTac[] player;
    private int row;  //<---
    private  int col;  //""
    public TicTac(String name){
        this.name=name;
        playerTable=new int[2][2];
        activePlayer=0;
    }
    public boolean isValidMove(int row,int col){
        return (row>0&&row<4&&col>0&&col<4&&takenSquare[row-1][col-1]==false);
    }//isValidmove
    public void setMove (String move){
        StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(move);
        this.row= Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        this.col= Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        if (isValidMove(row-1,col-1)){
            player[activePlayer].takenSquare[row-1][col-1]=true;
            player[activePlayer].playerTable[row-1][col-1]=table[row-1][col-1];
        }
        activePlayer=1-activePlayer;
    }
    public static String drawTable(){

        String a="";
        a+=(drawSquare(0,0)+"|");
        a+=(drawSquare(0,1)+"|");
        a+=(drawSquare(0,2)+'\n');
        a+=("-----------")+'\n';
        a+=drawSquare(1,0)+"|";
        a+=drawSquare(1,1)+"|";
        a+=(drawSquare(1,2)+'\n');
        a+=("-----------")+'\n';
        a+=drawSquare(2,0)+"|";
        a+=drawSquare(2,1)+"|";
        a+=(drawSquare(2,2));
        return"a";
    }

    public static String drawSquare(int x,int y){
        if (player[0].isTaken(x,y)) {
            return "O";
        }   else if (player[1].isTaken(x,y)) return "X";
        else return "   ";  

    }
    public boolean isTaken(int x,int y) {
        return takenSquare[x][y];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

                //TicTac player[];
                player=new TicTac[2];
                player[0]=new TicTac("baggelis");
                player[1]=new TicTac("Giorgaras");
                player[0].setMove("1 2");
                System.out.println(TicTac.drawTable());


    }


}
```

Comment: @user3183162 All of this answer + please follow naming conventions (not all, but at least the one that says that class names should begin with Uppercase) + remember to post a full stacktrace next time + the static variable _player_ is never initialized inside the tictac class, then when you enter drawSquare() and execute a method on player[0]... booom! There's your NullPointerException

Comment: @HernánErasmo  can you tell me how can i initialize it ?? im kind nooby

Comment: @user3183162 You already intend to do it, look at the modified code above. In main method if you comment out the repetitive array declaration `//TicTac player[];` it's picking the correct version of your array. Try to execute the above modified code as a whole.

Comment: @PopoFibo   i commented it out and it came up with cannot find symbol like no declaration to the variable player

Comment: @PopoFibo how can i do it seperatedly?? like in different .class files

Answer (score 1):

This should make your code work. At least it won't throw a NullPointerException at drawSquare()

```
public class tictac {
... //rest of the code

    static tictac[] player = { 
        new tictac( "PlayerName1" ),
        new tictac( "PlayerName2" ),
    };

... //more code

}
```

EDIT: Ok, perhaps I wasn't as straightforward as I thought. This is the full code for the class tictac that I want you to run

```
import java.util.*;
import acm.program.*;
public class tictac{
    private String name;
    int [][]table=new int [][]{
    {8,1,6},
    {3,5,7},
    {4,9,2}
    };
    int activePlayer;
    boolean [][]takenSquare= new boolean [2][2];
    int [][]playerTable; //gia tin niki
    static tictac[] player = { 
        new tictac( "PlayerName1" ),
        new tictac( "PlayerName2" ),
    };
    private int row;  //<---
    private  int col;  //""
    public tictac(String name){
        this.name=name;
        playerTable=new int[2][2];
        activePlayer=0;
    }
    public boolean isValidMove(int row,int col){
        return (row>0&&row<4&&col>0&&col<4&&takenSquare[row-1][col-1]==false);
    }//isValidmove
    public void setMove (String move){
        StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(move);
        this.row= Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        this.col= Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        if (isValidMove(row-1,col-1)){
            player[activePlayer].takenSquare[row-1][col-1]=true;
            player[activePlayer].playerTable[row-1][col-1]=table[row-1][col-1];
        }
        activePlayer=1-activePlayer;
    }
    public static String drawTable(){

        String a="";
        a+=(drawSquare(0,0)+"|");
        a+=(drawSquare(0,1)+"|");
        a+=(drawSquare(0,2)+'\n');
        a+=("-----------")+'\n';
        a+=drawSquare(1,0)+"|";
        a+=drawSquare(1,1)+"|";
        a+=(drawSquare(1,2)+'\n');
        a+=("-----------")+'\n';
        a+=drawSquare(2,0)+"|";
        a+=drawSquare(2,1)+"|";
        a+=(drawSquare(2,2));
        return"a";
    }

    public static String drawSquare(int x,int y){
        if (player[0].isTaken(x,y)) {
            return "O";
        }   else if (player[1].isTaken(x,y)) return "X";
        else return "   ";  

    }
    public boolean isTaken(int x,int y) {
        return takenSquare[x][y];
    }
}
```

Comment: it didnt work.. initially it said that it was already declared and after i commented out my old constructor it said constructor cannot be appled to given types required : no arguements found string

Comment: okey i run it but the error  this time is out of bounds 

line  return takenSquare[x][y]
   if (player[0].isTaken(x,y)) {
a+=(drawSquare(0,2)+'\n');